# What's a "Dweller of hell"?

Tags: terminology, jahannam

In the following passage, what's a "dweller of hell"? A dead human, or some non-human being?

> Abu Umama narrated: “The Messenger of God said, ‘Everyone that God
>   admits into paradise will be married to 72 wives; two of them are
>   houris and seventy of his inheritance of the [female] **dwellers of
>   hell**. All of them will have libidinous sex organs and he will have an
>   ever-erect penis.’ ”
>
> Sunan Ibn Majah, Zuhd (Book of Abstinence) 39

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe this refers to [intercession](https://www.al-islam.org/inquiries-about-shia-islam-sayyid-moustafa-al-qazwini/intercession-shafaah) (i.e., asking Allah to remove someone from hell); another version of the hadith highlights this:

> That the Messenger of Allah said: "There are six things with Allah for the martyr. He is forgiven with the first flow of blood (he suffers), he is shown his place in Paradise, he is protected from punishment in the grave, secured from the greatest terror, the crown of dignity is placed upon his head - and its gems are better than the world and what is in it - **he is married to seventy two wives along Al-Huril-'Ayn of Paradise, and he may intercede for seventy of his close relatives.**" -- ([sunnah.com](http://sunnah.com/tirmidhi/22/46), listed as hasan (good))

According to the above hadith, the martyr can intercede for 70 "dwellers of hell" who are relatives and are being punished in hell (for whatever reason).

Keep in mind, though, that the version of the hadith in the question is described as da’if (weak) of [sunnah.com](http://www.sunnah.com/urn/1294400), so it's best to take all this with a grain of salt.

Comment: Are the 70 women blood relatives, non-blood relatives, or either?

Comment: @AndrewGrimm The Arabic commentary of one of the narrators "Hisham ibn Khalid" in suann ibn Majah http://sunnah.com/urn/1294400 about "inheritance" is that it refers to a couple of women whoms husbands entered hell, so that people of paradise "inherited" them as spouses and gave an example the wife of Pharao http://legacy.quran.com/66/11 so one could conclude that it doesn't exactly mean blood relatives.

Answer (score 4):

This is the [hadith](http://sunnah.com/urn/1294400) you are referring to:

> There is no one whom Allah will admit to Paradise but Allah will marry him to seventy-two wives, two from houris and seventy from his inheritance from the people of Hell, all of whom will have desirable front passages and he will have a male member that never becomes flaccid (i.e., soft and limp).
>
> ما من أحد يدخله الله الجنة إلا زوجه الله عز وجل ثنتين وسبعين زوجة ثنتين من الحور العين وسبعين من ميراثه من أهل النار ما منهن واحدة إلا ولها قبل شهي وله ذكر لا ينثنى

The dwellers of hell in the translation you are referring to means people who ended up in hell, while their wives ended up in paradise. The wives of those 70 men are married to a believer in paradise.

This is for the sake of clarification only. As you can see from the link, this is a da'if (weak) hadith.

This hadith in Sunnan ibn Majah was narrated by Muhammad ibn Yazid, through Hisham ibn Khalid, through Khalid ibn Yazid, through Yazid ibn 'Abdul-Rahman (his father), through Khalid ibn Ma'daan, through Abu Umama to the Prophet. Khalid ibn Yazid ibn Abi Malik is very weak, and none of his hadiths are considered authentic.